# Install wkhtmltopdf on heroku

Tags: heroku, wkhtmltopdf

In order to run wkhtmltopdf on heroku it is required to setup a buildpack that download and install wkhtml after the main app deploy.

All the available buildpacks are pretty old and point to a library download URL at download.gna.org/.. which is no longer available.

Can anybody point me to a correct buildpack, or maybe suggest how and what to change in to the following buildpacks in order to work? I guess it would be enough to change the download URL but I don't know what a correct URL looks like

https://github.com/dscout/wkhtmltopdf-buildpack/blob/master/bin/compile

https://github.com/barsoom/wkhtmltopdf-buildpack/blob/master/bin/compile

https://github.com/rafaelp/heroku-buildpack-wkhtmltopdf/blob/master/bin/compile

https://github.com/neofreko/wkhtmltopdf-buildpack/blob/master/bin/compile

Answer (score 3):

Use: https://github.com/tutorcruncher/pydf

It just works, we use it to generate tens of thousands of PDFs each month, both on heroku and on dockerized deployments.

Unlike the buildpack based approach pydf installs with the wkhtmltopdf binary included making it very easy to use.

(admission: I built pydf)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the one found on the Heroku pages?   https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/homelight/wkhtmltox-buildpack

Comment: FWIW - that buildpack states that it is only compatible with the Cedar-14 stack (which is deprecated).

Comment: After add this build pack, how can we use this wkhtmltopdf command ?